# GCC error: incomplete type 'claculator' used in nested name specifier

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction

I develope a library, when I compile my code with GCC (in Windows with CodeBlocks), The source code doesn't compile and this error appears:

**error: incomplete type 'claculator' used in nested name specifier.**

I write a sample code that generate this error exactly:

```
class claculator;

template<class T>
class my_class
{
    public:

    void test()
    {
        // GCC error: incomplete type 'claculator' used in nested name specifier
        int x = claculator::add(1, 2);
    }

    T m_t;
};

// This class SHOULD after my_class.
// I can not move this class to top of my_class.
class claculator
{
    public:

    static int add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    my_class<int> c;
    c.test();

    return 0;
}
```

How can I solve this error?

Note that my source code compiled successfully in Visual Studio.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is it impossible to move `claculator` declaration (not definition!) before the template?

Comment: Any particular reason for using 'claculator' instead of 'calculator'?  Also, why can't you move the definition of `my_class` below `claculator`?  That sounds like a homework requirement...

Comment: @Jonathan: Sorry, miss spelled :D
This is not my actual source code, this source generates the error exactly, My actual source code is too complicated for moving classes. for example I use `calculator` in `my_class` and also I use `my_class` in `calculator`.

Comment: Your program is ill-formed. If you make `my_class` a non-template, all compilers will complain, because you  cannot access `claculator::add` for an incomplete type `claculator`. This should be the case for templates also, but some compilers (like VC++) give templates a somewhat relaxed treatment. They **erroneously** postpone checks until instantiation time. They really shouldn't, the standard is rather explicit about it.

Comment: @n.m: This is a sample code, I write it for generating the error, This is not a real source code but generates the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its very simple. Define `test()` **after** the definition  of `calculator` class as:

```
class calculator;

template<class T>
class my_class
{
    public:

    void test(); //Define it after the definition of `calculator`

    T m_t;
};

// This class SHOULD after my_class.
// I can not move this class to top of my_class.
class calculator
{
    public:

    static int add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }
};

//Define it here!
template<class T>
void my_class<T>::test()
{
     int x = calculator::add(1, 2);
}
```

In this way, the *complete* definition of `calculator` is known to the compiler when it parses the *definition* of `test()`.

Comment: small note. OP wanted `claculator` ... not `calculator` :)

Comment: @Nawaz: its possible that this idea wouldn't work in a more real-world example, because the template implementation usually has to reside in the same header as the definition.

Comment: @iammilind: I think that is spelling mistake in his code. he might want to spell it correctly as I did.

Comment: @Vlad: He can define the function in the header as well.

Comment: @Nawaz: Let me explain my point. The OP insists that the definition of `my_class` precedes the definition of `claculator` -- that is, `"claculator.h"` #includes `"my_class.h"`. However the _whole_ template must be in `"my_class.h"`. That would make a problem again.

Comment: @Vlad: If you do that, then that is the problem. That is why this is the solution. BTW, you can `#include "claculator.h"` after the definition of `my_class` in `my_class.h` and then can define the `test()` function after `#include "claculator.h"`.

Comment: @Nawaz: yes, #including after the declaration is the solution.